# Most efficient way to break string up into substrings of equal length in R

Tags: r

I have around 3 million sequences of variable length that I want to break into overlapping substrings. Currently, this is the way I am doing it:

```
sequences1 <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(1000000, 15)  
sequences2 <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(1000000, 17)  
sequences3 <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(1000000, 18)  

sequences <- c(sequences1, sequences2, sequences3)

n = 4 #Number of characters in subsequence

subsequences <- sapply(sequences, function(x)
                substring(
                  x, seq(from = 1, to = (nchar(x) - n + 1)), seq(from = n, to = nchar(x))
                )))
```

What would the most efficient way of doing this be? It would be nice if it could be parallelized.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the most efficient way of doing this, but we can use `mclapply` from `parallel` to parallelize it.

```
  subsequences <- mclapply(sequences, function(x){
  substring(
    x, seq(from = 1, to = (nchar(x) - n + 1)), seq(from = n, to = nchar(x)))
  })
names(subsequences) <- sequences
```